# findViewById do not see the id of my EditText

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

I've got an `EditText()`:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/СA_EtFirN"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/CA_EtFirN"
            android:textColor="@color/SSA_TvColor"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

So as you see `android:id="@+id/СA_EtFirN"`. Then I've got an `Activity.java` and I want to define my `EditText()`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts);

    Log.i(TAG, "Start definition");
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CA_Tv1);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CA_EtFirN);
}
```

But the id `CA_EtFirN` is underlined with red. So my program don't see it. Any ideas?

My `R.id`

```
public final class R {
public static final class array {
    public static final int SSA_Sp=0x7f070000;
}
public static final class attr {
}
public static final class color {
    public static final int CA_BgColor=0x7f060005;
    public static final int CA_TvColor=0x7f060006;
    public static final int CGA_BgColor=0x7f060007;
    public static final int CGA_TvColor=0x7f060008;
    public static final int MA_BgColor=0x7f060001;
    public static final int MA_TvColor=0x7f060000;
    public static final int SSA_BgColor=0x7f060002;
    public static final int SSA_SpColor=0x7f060004;
    public static final int SSA_TvColor=0x7f060003;
}
public static final class dimen {
    /**  Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. 

     Customize dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml (such as
     screen margins) for sw720dp devices (e.g. 10" tablets) in landscape here.

     */
    public static final int activity_horizontal_margin=0x7f040000;
    public static final int activity_vertical_margin=0x7f040001;
}
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    public static final int pic_congrat_activity=0x7f020001;
}
public static final class id {
    public static final int CA_BtnAutoAdd=0x7f0a000d;
    public static final int CA_BtnHardAdd=0x7f0a000b;
    public static final int CA_Tv1=0x7f0a0003;
    public static final int CA_Tv2=0x7f0a000c;
    public static final int CGA_IV=0x7f0a0002;
    public static final int CGA_Tv1=0x7f0a0000;
    public static final int CGA_TvDays=0x7f0a0001;
    public static final int MA_BtnCont=0x7f0a0011;
    public static final int MA_BtnSet=0x7f0a0012;
    public static final int MA_Tv1=0x7f0a000e;
    public static final int MA_Tv2=0x7f0a0010;
    public static final int MA_TvDays=0x7f0a000f;
    public static final int SSA_BtnCont=0x7f0a001c;
    public static final int SSA_BtnFemale=0x7f0a001f;
    public static final int SSA_BtnMale=0x7f0a001e;
    public static final int SSA_ETDay=0x7f0a0014;
    public static final int SSA_ETMonth=0x7f0a0008;
    public static final int SSA_ETYear=0x7f0a000a;
    public static final int SSA_RbHun=0x7f0a0017;
    public static final int SSA_RbTen=0x7f0a0016;
    public static final int SSA_Tv1=0x7f0a0013;
    public static final int SSA_Tv2=0x7f0a0015;
    public static final int SSA_Tv3=0x7f0a0019;
    public static final int SSA_Tv4=0x7f0a001a;
    public static final int SSA_Tv5=0x7f0a001d;
    public static final int SSA_TvDot1=0x7f0a0007;
    public static final int SSA_TvDot2=0x7f0a0009;
    public static final int SSA_TvSel=0x7f0a001b;
    public static final int SSS_RbTho=0x7f0a0018;
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f0a0020;
    public static final int СA_ETDay=0x7f0a0006;
    public static final int СA_ETSecondName=0x7f0a0005;
    public static final int СA_EtFirN=0x7f0a0004;
}
public static final class layout {
    public static final int congrat=0x7f030000;
    public static final int contacts=0x7f030001;
    public static final int eighth_march=0x7f030002;
    public static final int main=0x7f030003;
    public static final int start_set=0x7f030004;
    public static final int twenty_third_feb=0x7f030005;
}
public static final class menu {
    public static final int main=0x7f090000;
}
public static final class string {
    public static final int CA_BtnAdd=0x7f050018;
    public static final int CA_BtnAutoAdd=0x7f050021;
    public static final int CA_BtnHardAdd=0x7f050020;
    public static final int CA_ETDays=0x7f05001d;
    public static final int CA_ETMonth=0x7f05001e;
    public static final int CA_ETYear=0x7f05001f;
    public static final int CA_EtFirN=0x7f05001b;
    public static final int CA_EtSecN=0x7f05001c;
    public static final int CA_Tv1=0x7f050019;
    public static final int CA_Tv2=0x7f05001a;
    public static final int CGA_Tv1=0x7f050022;
    public static final int MA_BtnCont=0x7f050006;
    public static final int MA_BtnSet=0x7f050007;
    public static final int MA_Tv1=0x7f050003;
    public static final int MA_Tv2=0x7f050005;
    public static final int MA_TvDays=0x7f050004;
    public static final int SSA_BtnCont=0x7f050010;
    public static final int SSA_BtnFemale=0x7f05000f;
    public static final int SSA_BtnMale=0x7f05000e;
    public static final int SSA_ETDays=0x7f050011;
    public static final int SSA_ETMonth=0x7f050012;
    public static final int SSA_ETYear=0x7f050013;
    public static final int SSA_RbHun=0x7f050016;
    public static final int SSA_RbTen=0x7f050015;
    public static final int SSA_RbTho=0x7f050017;
    public static final int SSA_Tv1=0x7f050008;
    public static final int SSA_Tv2=0x7f050009;
    public static final int SSA_Tv3=0x7f05000a;
    public static final int SSA_Tv4=0x7f05000b;
    public static final int SSA_Tv5=0x7f05000d;
    public static final int SSA_TvDot=0x7f050014;
    public static final int SSA_TvSel=0x7f05000c;
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f050001;
    public static final int app_name=0x7f050000;
    public static final int hello_world=0x7f050002;
}
```

P.S With `TextView` it is OK.

Comment: Try a Project/Clean and a reload.

Comment: Side note: does this ID make much sense to you? :)

Comment: Check your imports for android.R :)

Comment: I guess the prob with the **R**!! import your application **R** !

Comment: Is only `CA_EtFirN` underlined or the whole `R.id.CA_EtFirN`? What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to copy/paste id from layout.xml into the code (or vice versa) to be sure you didn't mix cyrillic and latin characters in names.

Comment: It is very strange)) if i copy `CA_EtFirN` it is OK. But if I write the name of id (the same name, I've checked!!!) it is an error)

Comment: @SergaRUS maybe it's because of using punto switcher or stuff like that ))

Comment: I think the reason is in 'C' letter. In both Cyrillic and Latin it looks the same and locate at the same keyboard button, so often when Windows switches keyboard layout with delay, this causes little problems )

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean the project and rebuild, sometimes R.java is not updated well.

Answer (score 2):

It is very strange)) if i copy CA_EtFirN it is OK. But if I write the name of id (the same name, I've checked!!!) it is an error)

Answer (score 1):

Check in your java class for import statement android.R 
if it exists delete that import statement and then clean your project and then run again and comment me about the result